# Partially setting text colour within an ExtJS grid cell

Tags: css, extjs, formatting, extjs4.2

I have a ExtJS 4.2 grid column (as part of a PHP MVC 3 website) relating to status of a set of processes for items. This column returns a string of three-letter abbreviations per process that has been completed, separated by spaces, for example `Was Pre Cut` would be an item that had been Washed, Prepared and Cut, and `Was Scr Pee` would be an item that had been Washed, Scrubbed and Peeled.

However, the desired functionality would be to retrieve *all* the processes, and style each entry to show whether it had been completed; en example would be `<green>Was Pre</green> Cut` would denote an item that has been washed and prepared but not cut.

Is this possible? Is this something where I pass the values and corresponding style formats per process as an array object instead of a string, and generate the desired formatting via the cell's renderer, or am I being optimistic about the capability of a grid column's renderer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A column renderer gives you a runtime that output HTML, you could hardly overestimate the capabilities of that...

I am not sure I completely understand your problematic, but here's a starter example. Given a list of possible processes, it displays all processes for each records, and highlight the processes that are flagged for this record ([example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zbf57/)):

```
var processes = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Bat']; // all available processes

new Ext.grid.Panel({
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,width: 400
    ,height: 200
    ,forceFit: true

    ,store: {
        fields: ['id', 'status', 'statusDetails']
        ,data: [
            {id: 1, status: 'Foo Bar', statusDetails: ['Foo', 'Bar']}
            ,{id: 2, status: 'Bar Baz', statusDetails: ['Bar', 'Baz']}
            ,{id: 3, status: 'Baz Bat', statusDetails: ['Baz', 'Bat']}
        ]
    }

    ,columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'id'
        ,text: "ID"
        ,width: 40
    },{
        dataIndex: 'status'
        ,text: "Status"
        ,renderer: function(value, md, record) {
            md.tdCls = 'processes-cell'; // gives us a hook for CSS
            return Ext.Array.map(processes, function(process) {
                var statusDetails = record.get('statusDetails');
                // possible alternative:
                // var statusDetails = record.get('status').split(' ');
                return '<div class="process ' + process + ' '
                + (statusDetails.indexOf(process) !== -1 ? 'on' : 'off')
                + '">' + process
                + '</div>';
            }).join('');
        }
    }]
});
```

And style that to your heart's content. For example:

```
.processes-cell .process {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.processes-cell .process.off {
    background-color: lightpink;
}
.processes-cell .process.on {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.processes-cell .x-grid-cell-inner {
    padding: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ha yep rixo beat me to it. He is right you need to work with the `renderer` property for your column. I created a fiddle as well in case you might need to see another example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/872